# Send multiple data based on group in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Sorry for the unclear title.
So, the case to be like this.

Build messaging app. I have three tables, "Sent Messages", "Contact" and "Contact Group".
Lists data of Contact table

```
id | name | number | group
1  | Name 1 | 089123 | 1
2  | Name 2 | 089876 | 1
3  | Name 3 | 089456 | 2
```

Lists data of Contact Group table

```
id | name | region
1  | Group 1 | North
2  | Group 2 | West
```

Lists data of Sent Messages table

```
id | destination_number| receiver_name | message | datetime
1  | 089876 | Name 2 | hello | AM02:00
2  | 089876 | Name 2 | this is broadcast msg | AM03:00
3  | 089123 | Name 1 | this is broadcast msg | AM03:00
```

Nah, in Compose Message form there option to send message by contact or group. If I **choose group option**, then we can called it "Broadcast Message". Required field to send are destination number, receiver name and text message.

How can to store that broadcast concept / multiple rows with single strike into database??

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What is the purpose of that `number` column? Is it used to identify the user? And if so, why are you not using the `id` column for that purpose? I ask these questions because I'd like to offer a solution and would like to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: @Bogdan thanks for the answer. Actually this app is to be like SMS gateway, so I sud use (phone) number :)

Comment: @Bogdan sorry forgot. Yes the number is unique and it used to identify the user too. But instead of ID, I should use number because this a SMS gateway app, and in Sent Messages there destination_number column that will be trigger modem to send the SMS